# Restkit Core data one to one mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am new to rest kit2.0. having some issue with one to many relation ship.
below are my model, restkit implementations & json response.

[image]

```
@interface **DocumentCategory** : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * categoryDeleted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * categoryDeviceIconUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * categoryId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * categoryName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * categoryServerIconUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *documentObjects;
@end

@interface **AppDocument** : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * documentDeleted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentDesc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentIconDeviceUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentIconServerUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * documentId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentPdfDeviceUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentPdfServerUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentVideoDeviceUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * documentVideoServerUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DocumentCategory *categoryObject;

@end
```

here is my rest kit implementation

```
    RKEntityMapping *documentCategoryMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DocumentCategory" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
        [documentCategoryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                                      @"Id":@"categoryId",
                                                                      @"CategoryDeleted":@"categoryDeleted",
                                                                      @"CaegoryName":@"categoryName",
                                                                      @"CategoryServerIconUrl":@"categoryServerIconUrl"
                                                                      }];



    RKEntityMapping *appDocumentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"AppDocument" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
        [appDocumentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"Id":   @"documentId",
                                                      @"AppDescription":   @"documentDesc",
                                                      @"documentDeleted":   @"documentDeleted",
                                                      @"AppIcon":     @"documentIconServerUrl",
                                                      @"Title":        @"documentName",
                                                      @"AppPDFurl":   @"documentPdfServerUrl",
                                                      @"AppVideourl":     @"documentVideoServerUrl"
                                                      }];
        [appDocumentMapping setIdentificationAttributes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"documentId", nil]];


 [appDocumentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"AppCategoryIDId" toKeyPath:@"categoryObject" withMapping:documentCategoryMapping]];


RKResponseDescriptor *documentDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:appDocumentMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"AppHelp/AppDetails" keyPath:@"d.results" statusCodes:statusCodes];
//[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:categoryDescriptor,documentDescriptor,appDetailsDescriptor,appDetailsForVersionDescriptor,errorDescriptor, nil]];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:categoryDescriptor,documentDescriptor,errorDescriptor, nil]];




 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"AppHelp/AppCategory"  parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
         {
             //  NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %@", mappingResult);

             //[self hideProgressHUD];








             [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"AppHelp/AppDetails"  parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
              {
                  //  NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %@", mappingResult);

                  [self hideProgressHUD];
              }
                                                       failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
              {
                  //NSLog(@"error %@",[error description]);
                  [self hideProgressHUD];
              }];






         }
        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             //NSLog(@"error %@",[error description]);
             [self hideProgressHUD];
         }];
```

With above implementation I am getting below error message.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFNumber 0xbd5bad0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CategoryServerIconUrl.'
```

thanks for your valuable time, solution/help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Below is the json response.

For the very first request I get below response.

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(1)",
          "etag": "W/\"3\"",
          "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.AppCategoryItem"
        },
        "ContentTypeID": "0x01006A3A58069D41EF409018396EB125A5E9",

        "CaegoryName": "Productivity",
        "CategoryServerIconUrl": "http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com",
        "CategoryDeleted": false,
        "Id": 1,
        "ContentType": "Item",
        "Modified": "\/Date(1404806841000)\/",
        "Created": "\/Date(1403657024000)\/",
        "CreatedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(1)/CreatedBy"
          }
        },
        "CreatedById": 60,
        "ModifiedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(1)/ModifiedBy"
          }
        },
        "ModifiedById": 26215,
        "Owshiddenversion": 3,
        "Version": "1.0",
        "Attachments": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(1)/Attachments"
          }
        },
        "Path": "/sites/gis/Mobile Apps/Lists/AppCategory"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(2)",
          "etag": "W/\"3\"",
          "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.AppCategoryItem"
        },
        "ContentTypeID": "0x01006A3A58069D41EF409018396EB125A5E9",
        "CaegoryName": "Business",
        "CategoryServerIconUrl": "http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com",
        "CategoryDeleted": false,
        "Id": 2,
        "ContentType": "Item",
        "Modified": "\/Date(1404806874000)\/",
        "Created": "\/Date(1403657032000)\/",
        "CreatedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(2)/CreatedBy"
          }
        },
        "CreatedById": 60,
        "ModifiedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(2)/ModifiedBy"
          }
        },
        "ModifiedById": 26215,
        "Owshiddenversion": 3,
        "Version": "1.0",
        "Attachments": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(2)/Attachments"
          }
        },
        "Path": "/sites/gis/Mobile Apps/Lists/AppCategory"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(3)",
          "etag": "W/\"3\"",
          "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.AppCategoryItem"
        },
        "ContentTypeID": "0x01006A3A58069D41EF409018396EB125A5E9",
        "CaegoryName": "Connectivity",
        "CategoryServerIconUrl": "http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com",
        "CategoryDeleted": false,
        "Id": 3,
        "ContentType": "Item",
        "Modified": "\/Date(1404806911000)\/",
        "Created": "\/Date(1403657047000)\/",
        "CreatedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(3)/CreatedBy"
          }
        },
        "CreatedById": 60,
        "ModifiedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(3)/ModifiedBy"
          }
        },
        "ModifiedById": 26215,
        "Owshiddenversion": 3,
        "Version": "1.0",
        "Attachments": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(3)/Attachments"
          }
        },
        "Path": "/sites/gis/Mobile Apps/Lists/AppCategory"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(4)",
          "etag": "W/\"3\"",
          "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.AppCategoryItem"
        },
        "ContentTypeID": "0x01006A3A58069D41EF409018396EB125A5E9",
        "CaegoryName": "General",
        "CategoryServerIconUrl": "http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com",
        "CategoryDeleted": false,
        "Id": 4,
        "ContentType": "Item",
        "Modified": "\/Date(1404806934000)\/",
        "Created": "\/Date(1403823724000)\/",
        "CreatedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(4)/CreatedBy"
          }
        },
        "CreatedById": 23323,
        "ModifiedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(4)/ModifiedBy"
          }
        },
        "ModifiedById": 26215,
        "Owshiddenversion": 3,
        "Version": "1.0",
        "Attachments": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "/listdata.svc/AppCategory(4)/Attachments"
          }
        },
        "Path": "/sites/gis/Mobile Apps/Lists/AppCategory"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After receiving response, hitting another request to get below document json.

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "uri": ")",
          "etag": "W/\"1\"",
          "type": ""
        },
        "ContentTypeID": "0x010050E1B3AE1BFD2846A6ED8237F2BDDB29",
        "Title": "SkyMobile SRM",
        "AppCategoryID": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": ")/AppCategoryID"
          }
        },
        "AppCategoryIDId": 2,
        "AppDescription": "",
        "AppIcon": " ",
        "AppPDFurl": "",
        "AppVideourl": null,
        "Id": 1,
        "ContentType": "Item",
        "Modified": "\/Date(1403657407000)\/",
        "Created": "\/Date(1403657407000)\/",
        "CreatedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": ")/CreatedBy"
          }
        },
        "CreatedById": 60,
        "ModifiedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": ")/ModifiedBy"
          }
        },
        "ModifiedById": 60,
        "Owshiddenversion": 1,
        "Version": "1.0",
        "Attachments": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": ")/Attachments"
          }
        },
        "Path": "/ils"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note : I have two separate url one for category and another for document.
Document josn response contains **AppCategoryIDId** which is Category primary key.

Comment: Something is telling me you have a casing problem CategoryServerIconUrl != categoryServerIconUrl. How is it set in your core data model schema?

Comment: Thanks Marc for responding, actually if I remove property mapping i.e  [appDocumentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"AppCategoryIDId" toKeyPath:@"categoryObject" withMapping:documentCategoryMapping]]; error will go away however, there would not be any relationship between document and category.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of you data model file?

Comment: I have added, asked screen shot.

Comment: Show the JSON. The method is called on an `NSNumber` instance so you have a bigger problem than just a naming typo...

Comment: Good catch, the JSOn probably returns an integer at DocumentCategory property

Comment: Just added the json response.